# MySQL Select using one table's data as column for query

Tags: mysql

I have a database table which each row represents a column of data I'd like pulled for a query.  My table is:

```
tracked_pages
page_id | page_url     | page_name
-------------------------------------
1       | users.php    | Users
2       | auctions.php | Auctions
3       | receipts.php | Receipts
```

So essentially, I have another table that tracks each time a page is accessed by a logged-in user.  But these 3 pages are the only ones I'm really interested in right now.

This is not my actual query, but just to show how I'd write it if I just hand-wrote it, I'd do something like:

```
Select user.id, count(clicks1.id) As user_clicks, count(clicks2.id) As auction_clicks, count(clicks3.id) As receipt_clicks
From users
Left Join clicks As clicks1 On (users.id = clicks1.id And clicks1.page = 'users.php')
Left Join clicks As clicks2 On (users.id = clicks2.id And clicks2.page = 'auctions.php')
Left Join clicks As clicks3 On (users.id = clicks3.id And clicks.page = 'receipts.php')
Group By users.id
```

So I'd expect output similar to:

```
Output
user_id | user_clicks | auction_clicks | receipt_clicks
-------------------------------------------------------
1       | 54          | 16             | 16
2       | 27          | 22             | 12
3       | 32          | 24             | 38
```

However, I'd like the query to pull each column from the database instead of having to join the same table manually.  The reason is because the `tracked_pages` table can be updated through a management area and I don't want to have to go update the code each time they want to track a different page.

I know I could just perform a query to get the users, then as I loop through that I could perform another query to get the page counts, but I'm really wanting to make it just one query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
James

Comment: 'loop through that' ?? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Strawberry I just mean that I know I could get this data using multiple queries, but I don't want to.  I am trying to get the data using just one query.

Comment: I suspect that *you're* focusing on the wrong thing.  Hence my question, which remains unanswered.

Comment: That's fine. I suspect yours will be answered anyway.